# How to properly json_decode a Laravel Model

Tags: json, laravel, serialization, eloquent, json-deserialization

In an app i'm working on, there's a report feature which needs to process a huge report and then show it. So it was decided that the report will be handled by a Job, then rendered when it's ready.

However, the problem lies here:
In order to render the report after it's ready, i have to store the report data in the database. This data is stored in a field called 'values', in the reports table.
In order to store all the report data in this field, I use php's json_encode() (I am aware that laravel has a Model::toJson() method, but the data includes more than just models).

The data i'm storing looks like this:

```
$data = json_encode([
            'subtitle' => $subtitle,
            'logged_user' => $logged_user,
            'packages' => $packages, //this is the model. I also tried doing $packages->toJson()
            'columns' => $columns,
            'colspan' => $colspan,
            'request' => $request,
        ]);
```

When I try to access the data through json_decode(), the object turns into an array instead of a model object;
i tried doing

```
$my_object = new App\Models\MyModel($model_decoded_array)
```

But some of the object's properties and relations are lost (not all of them, go figure).

So I'm a bit lost here. Is there a way I can turn my models into Json, store them and then turn them back to their original state?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization has all the available logic for converting a Model to an array or JSON. The other option is PHP's `serialize()`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php and `unserialize()`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php which exists for the purpose of generating a "Storable" representation of an object.

Comment: @TimLewis serialize and unserialize worked! Thank you. I will mark the question as answered and point to your comment

Comment: Excellent! Yeah, feel free to add a self-answer in the section below and "accept" it (via the Checkmark) when you can (takes a couple days for self-answers).

Comment: @TimLewis You can also just copy & paste your comment into an answer and that way you can have one more accepted answer under your belt lol. If you want of course

Comment: I usually give the person asking the question the opportunity to show how they implemented my comment as a self-answer. As it stands, my comment would be a link-only answer, which is considered low quality for Stackoverflow 

Comment: @TimLewis Oh ok I see. Well that makes 2 new things you just taught me today. Thank you mate.

Comment: No problem! I appreciate you trying to give me the credit here, but all I did really was point you in the correct direction. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Credits to @TimLewis for the answer in the comments of the original question**

The solution to the issue was to just use php's serialize() function on the model before storing it, like so:

```
$data = json_encode([
            'subtitle' => $subtitle,
            'logged_user' => $logged_user,
            'packages' => serialize($packages),
            'columns' => $columns,
            'colspan' => $colspan,
            'request' => $request,
        ]);
```

Then, using unserialize() when trying to access it again:

```
$values = json_decode($report->values,true); //$report is a model passed to this file from a controller
$packages = unserialize($values['packages']); // values is the field in the db where the json data was stored
```

Comment: This isn't an ideal solution, and including more debugging information in the question (e.g. what is `$packages`, what does the JSON representation of it look like) would probably have helped get you a better answer.